# What is OWASP exactly?

Tags: owasp

Open Web Application Security Project

> Promotes secure software development
>   Oriented to the delivery of web oriented services
>   Focused primarily on the “back-end” than web-design issues
>   An open forum for discussion
>   A free resource for any development team

What is it? An operating system or software?

Answer (score 5):

Neither.

It is an organization that promotes secure software development.

As part of that effort they produce guidelines and software to help with this cause - software for testing and securing software. One piece of software is a [live CD](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Live_CD_Project) - the goal of this part of the project is "to make application security tools and documentation easily available.".

They are primarily concerned with secure web development.

Comment: You do realize that all Operating Systems _are_ software, right?

Comment: ya...i owasp and linux with gui looks the same..then why dont they call OWASP an OS...

Comment: Becuase OWASP is not the same as the live CD. The live CD is _part_ of what OWASP produce. The live CD contains some of what OWASP makes.

Answer (score 2):

From the [OWASP landing page](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page):

> The Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) is a 501c3 not-for-profit worldwide charitable organization focused on improving the security of application software

(If you are not familiar with the designation "501c3", it is a U.S. legal term that means that donations to the organization are tax deductible.)

More, from their [About page](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/About_OWASP):

> The Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) is an open community dedicated to enabling organizations to conceive, develop, acquire, operate, and maintain applications that can be trusted. All of the OWASP tools, documents, forums, and chapters are free and open to anyone interested in improving application security. We advocate approaching application security as a people, process, and technology problem because the most effective approaches to application security include improvements in all of these areas. We can be found at www.owasp.org.
>
> OWASP is a new kind of organization. Our freedom from commercial pressures allows us to provide unbiased, practical, cost-effective information about application security. OWASP is not affiliated with any technology company, although we support the informed use of commercial security technology. Similar to many open-source software projects, OWASP produces many types of materials in a collaborative, open way. The OWASP Foundation is a not-for-profit entity that ensures the project's long-term success.

Comment: owasp live cd and linux with gui looks the same..then why dont they call OWASP live cd an OS

Answer (score 1):

OWASP is neither an Operating System nor Software.

It is a non profit foundation that would focus more on improving the security practices of an application.

Some activities of the foundation include,

1. Community trainings related to Security
2. Periodically release Vulnerability rankings so that the Application development team could take those factors into consideration for building Secure Applications - OWASP Top 10
3. Build open Source tools that could be used in improving the Security side of the application. For instance, OWASP Dependency Check is a Software Composition Analysis tool that could be incorporated as part of your project.
4. Develop and provide other documentation such as Cheat sheets, Checklists related to Security.